# My header is not fitting properly on the top of web page?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to fit my header on the top but it's not fitting. Here is screenshot:

[image]

Here is my source code:

```
<header style="height: 50px;background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);">
    <div class="container"></div>
</header>
```

Can you please let me know, What's wrong here? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: [freenhand circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta) +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the following style in your css. There is default styles of browser which needs to overridden, in order to achieve the requirement.

```
html, body {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks  :) I'd accept after 12 minutes :) thanks agian

Comment: @Babaguru, It'll be a good idea to use a CSS Reset library to reduce browser specific styling in the future.

Answer (score 1):

All Browsers have default inbuilt CSS implemented, due to which the page appear misalligned. You need to add reset.css http://cssreset.com/

or  else add css code to disable browser default behaviour for example:

```
/* CSS reset */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
```